# how to add all string type numbers in list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, addition

I am trying to solve one problem in which I extracted data form text file and added it in list in python
now I want to add all those string numbers in list.

```
miles = ['47498.85', '70659.35', '31547.41', '106170.69', '84370.07', '46772.57', '3307.2', '65022.25', '85115.3', '17306.08', '39973.38', '53738.33', '19604.96']
```

This list is generated, now how do I add all the elements in this list as all elements are string type numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` with `sum`

```
result = sum(map(float, miles))

print(result)
```

Output:

`671086.44`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. All you need to do is iterate through the list and typecast each of the elements and add them to a variable.

```
sum = 0
for mile in miles:
    sum += float(mile)
print(sum)
```

you can convert the elements to any type you want. (int, double etc.)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
for i in range(len(miles)):
    miles[i] = float(miles[i])


result = sum(miles)
```

Second :

```
result = sum(list(map(float,miles)))
```